# Two different page numbers

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to have two different page numbers on the same page in Microsoft Word. I have an appendix to the document, that has its own numbering, but I want it to have also the numbers of the main document.

The document already has page numbering for the whole document? I created a new section with section break for the appendix, and removed link to previous section. Than I added another page number, and specified that the numbering should start at 1. Unfortunately, the original page numbers restarted numbering from 1, too.

Can I have one page number in the footer counting numbers from the beginning of the document, and section page number in footer counting pages for the appendix only? And I want also to have total numbers for the whole document and total page number for the appendix, so page numbers can be displayed / for the document and appendix.

Comment: See http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/page_numbering.html. This requires using bookmarks and fields.

Answer (score 0):

### You need to use bookmarks and fields to construct the extra set of page numbers.

This is set forth in [Greg Maxey's page on Page Numbering](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/page_numbering.html).

> **Dual Page Numbering**
>
> Sometimes people ask: How to display both "Page X of Y Pages" and
> "Page X of Z Pages" in the header/footer of a document?
>
> ```
> Where X is the page number referenced to Y or Z.
> Y is the total number of pages in the document.
> Z is the total number of pages in an individual "content" section.
> ```
>
> *Note:  I use the term "content section" to differentiate
> and define a document section formed with section breaks consisting of
> like content (e.g., Marketing, Sales, etc.) from sections formed with
> section breaks for the purpose of document layout (e.g., page
> orientation, etc.)*
>
> For this demonstration I have used an eight page document containing
> three sections. Section 1 contains two pages, section 2 contains three
> pages and section 3 contains three pages. The illustration below
> depicts dual numbering in section 1:
> [image: screenshot]
> Applying a dual numbering format in section 1 is simple. As shown in
> the illustration below, the numbering depicted above results from two
> field pairs. {Page} and {Numpages} fields are used for the X of Y
> format on the left and {Page} and {SectionPages} fields are used for
> the X of Z format on the right.
> [image: screenshot]
>
> - A problem arises in section 2 and subsequent sections using that simple process.  As you may know, a { PAGE } field can be formatted to
>   "Continue from ..." or "Start at ..." in each new section of a
>   document, but not both!!
> - Choose "Continue from previous section" in order that the left side page numbering continues throughout the document.  This is also
>   important for proper page number display in a table of contents.
> - However, this presents the problem depicted below:
>   [image: screenshot]
> - To resolve this issue, you can retrieve the page number of the last page of the previous section and subtract that value from the {Page}
>   field value returned in right hand side construction of the current
>   section header.
> - Add a bookmark to the last word or character in "content" section of your document.  Here I havae added a bookmark "S1" to the last word in
>   section 1. The bookmarks you add serve as the reference mark for
>   PageRef fields explained below.
>   [image: screenshot]
> - Each "content" section will require a unique field construction so the next step is to break the links between the "content" sections.
>   [image: screenshot]
>
> [image: screenshot]
>
> - Now modify the right hand side field construction in the "content" section 2 and 3 headers:
>   [image: screenshot]
> - The page value in the right hand construction is reset to 1 by subtracting the page number of the previous page form the page number of the current page.
>   [image: screenshot]
> - Here the page number of the last page in section 2 pages is subtracted.
>
> [image: screenshot]
>
> - Dual numbering in "content" section 2.
>
> [image: screenshot]
>
> - Dual numbering in "content" section 3.
>
> [image: screenshot]
>
> - Resulting numbering in table of contents.

---

Greg's page has vba to help with this and variations. The above is entirely from [his page](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/page_numbering.html).